# same rotations in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'd like to rotate a plane the same way as the camera rotates (that it looks like it doesn't move at all)

my animate() function for the camera:

```
camera.position.x = Math.sin(t/1500)*200;
    camera.position.y = 250;
    camera.position.z = Math.cos(t/1500)*200;
```

And the plane (done with CubeGeometry):

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 1, 50),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF00FF}));
    plane.position.y = 115;
    plane.position.z = 25;
```

Which parameters does the plane need that it looks like standing still?

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, Totally forgetting that all the time :(

Answer (score 0):

Hope that including the below code may help you. As the camera rotates, the plane will also rotate to look towards the camera.

plane.lookAt( camera.position );